zkSync Finality- what happens if I spend funds before finality
If Ethereum deems the zkSync batch invalid, does the state rolls back to before the invalid block?
If so, does this mean you need to be careful using funds within the first 24hours? What happens if funds are transferred into a protocol or something?
The zkSync docs effectively say this but just wanted to make sure I fully understood what happens if the block is invalid

In the unlikely event that the initial bridging transaction (that you’ve done to receive the funds on zkSync) is not finalized on L1 and needs to be rolled back, zkSync can revert the transactions on L2. This rollback would also include any subsequent transactions that were performed using the funds from the initial bridging transaction.
And the transactions (that are done using the funds acquired from the initial bridging transaction) are traced using Transaction Dependency Tracking mechanism, which includes:

Chain of Transactions: Each transaction on the zkSync network can be traced back to its origin. When funds are bridged from L1 to L2, this initial transaction is recorded, and any subsequent transactions using these funds are linked.

Dependency Graph: The system maintains a dependency graph that maps out how funds move from one transaction to another. This graph is crucial for identifying which transactions are affected if the initial transaction is rolled back.


You can refer to this GitHub discussion for better understanding.
